# @angular Animations Build Error - has no exported member 'AnimationBuilder'

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I recently performed an

> **npm update**

command and pulled down Angular version 4.2.6. However, when I ran

> **ng build**

I received a bunch of build errors all related to @angular/animations.

See below:

```
[alobban@linuxlaptop-advfrtsvr-advantagefreight-com afngine-ng2]$ ng build
Hash: eeeb38b2753a21366397                                                               
Time: 34119ms
chunk    {0} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 870 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {1} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 160 kB {5} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 714 kB {5} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {3} scripts.bundle.js, scripts.bundle.js.map (scripts) 471 kB {5} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {4} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 3.66 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {5} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]

ERROR in /usr/share/nginx/afngine-ng2/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/animations/src/animation_builder.d.ts (8,10): Module '"/usr/share/nginx/afngine-ng2/node_modules/@angular/animations/animations"' has no exported member 'AnimationBuilder'.
/usr/share/nginx/afngine-ng2/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/animations/src/animation_builder.d.ts (8,28): Module '"/usr/share/nginx/afngine-ng2/node_modules/@angular/animations/animations"' has no exported member 'AnimationFactory'.
/usr/share/nginx/afngine-ng2/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/animations/src/animation_builder.d.ts (8,65): Module '"/usr/share/nginx/afngine-ng2/node_modules/@angular/animations/animations"' has no exported member 'AnimationOptions'.

ERROR in /usr/share/nginx/afngine-ng2/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/animations/src/providers.d.ts (5,22): Non-abstract class 'InjectableAnimationEngine' does not implement inherited abstract member 'flush' from class 'AnimationEngine'.
/usr/share/nginx/afngine-ng2/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/animations/src/providers.d.ts (5,22): Non-abstract class 'InjectableAnimationEngine' does not implement inherited abstract member 'listen' from class 'AnimationEngine'.
/usr/share/nginx/afngine-ng2/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/animations/src/providers.d.ts (5,22): Non-abstract class 'InjectableAnimationEngine' does not implement inherited abstract member 'onInsert' from class 'AnimationEngine'.
/usr/share/nginx/afngine-ng2/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/animations/src/providers.d.ts (5,22): Non-abstract class 'InjectableAnimationEngine' does not implement inherited abstract member 'onRemove' from class 'AnimationEngine'.
/usr/share/nginx/afngine-ng2/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/animations/src/providers.d.ts (5,22): Non-abstract class 'InjectableAnimationEngine' does not implement inherited abstract member 'registerTrigger' from class 'AnimationEngine'.
/usr/share/nginx/afngine-ng2/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/animations/src/providers.d.ts (5,22): Non-abstract class 'InjectableAnimationEngine' does not implement inherited abstract member 'setProperty' from class 'AnimationEngine'.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is what I did to resolve these issues. I ran command:

```
npm i @angular/animations@latest
```

Or deleting the node_modules folder and re-running

```
npm cache clean

npm i
```

as recommended by @Z. Bagley

Comment: Worth noting it was likely an older package stuck in your `node_modules`. Deleting the node_modules folder and `npm cache clean` will typically resolve these issues as long as you keep your `package.json` up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Such an error can appear when upgrading angular. 
You can solve by installing latest animate library for angular 
Though important is also to update import statements.

In my case - upgrade from Angular 5 to Angular 7 - I had to change:
from:

```
import { animate, state, style, transition, trigger } from '@angular/core';
```

to:

```
import { animate, state, style, transition, trigger } from '@angular/animations';
```